# Redirect loop when x509 authentication fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, x509

I have spring boot application with x509 authentication. My problem is that when authentication fails i get redirect loop instead of error screen.

When authentication fails i throw UsernameNotFoundException loadUserDetails from method in ArhivX509UserDetailsService.java

My code is as follows:

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("x509UserDetailsService")
private AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> iX509UserDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity pHttp) throws Exception {
    //@formatter:off
    pHttp
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/error401").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .x509()
            .subjectPrincipalRegex("(.*)")
            .authenticationUserDetailsService(iX509UserDetailsService)
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new X509ErrorCheckerFilter(),  X509AuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(new LoggerMDCFilter(),  X509ErrorCheckerFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint())
            .accessDeniedPage(AppUrls.ERROR_401)
            .and()
        .requiresChannel()
            .anyRequest()
            .requiresSecure()
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .and()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("SESSION", "JSESSIONID")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("http://www.google.com")
            .permitAll();
    //@formatter:on
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint() {
    return new AuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest pRequest, HttpServletResponse pResponse,
                AuthenticationException pAuthException) throws IOException, ServletException {
            pResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    };
}
}
```

ArhivX509UserDetailsService.java

```
@Service("x509UserDetailsService")
public class ArhivX509UserDetailsService
        implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> {
    @Autowired
    private IUserProfileService iUserProfileService;

    @Autowired
    private ICheckCertificateService iCheckCertService;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserDetails(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken pToken) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        X509Certificate tCertificate = (X509Certificate) pToken.getCredentials();
        String tSubjectDN = tCertificate.getSubjectDN().toString().toUpperCase();
        ProfilKorisnika tProfilKorisnika = iUserProfileService.getUserProfile(tSubjectDN);

        if (tProfilKorisnika == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Pogreška kod prijave korisnika.");
        }

        return tProfilKorisnika;

    }
}
```

X509ErrorCheckerFilter.java

```
public class X509ErrorCheckerFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    private static final String DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL = "/error401";

    private static final String[] UNAUTHENTICATED_URLS = { "/webjars/**", "/error", "/error401", "/login",
            "/logout" };

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest pRequest, ServletResponse pResponse, FilterChain pChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest tHttpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) pRequest;
        HttpServletResponse tHttpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) pResponse;

        String tContextRoot = tHttpRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getContextPath();
        String tUri = tHttpRequest.getRequestURI().replaceFirst(tContextRoot, "");

        if (isUriSecured(tUri)) {
            Authentication tAuthentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            AuthenticationException tException = (AuthenticationException) tHttpRequest
                    .getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);

            if (tException != null || tAuthentication == null) {
                RequestDispatcher tRd = tHttpRequest.getRequestDispatcher(DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL);
                tRd.forward(tHttpRequest, tHttpResponse);
                return;
            }
        }

        pChain.doFilter(pRequest, pResponse);

    }

    private boolean isUriSecured(String pRequestURI) {
        boolean tResult = true;
        for (String tUrl : UNAUTHENTICATED_URLS) {
            if (pRequestURI.startsWith(tUrl)) {
                tResult = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return tResult;
    }

}
```

If you need more details please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Applying permitAll() to /error401 means that when the security filterchain is finished executing, the request will be processed normally, regardless of whether or not there is an Authentication in the current SecurityContext.

X509ErrorCheckerFilter is forwarding all unauthenticated requests to /error401 from within the filterchain, so permitAll() is never applied. Instead, the forwarded request goes through the filterchain again and fails authentication, causing the circular redirect.

To resolve this, you have several options. Here are a couple:

### 1. Disable Security for error endpoints

you can disable security for endpoints using [web.ignoring()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html#ignoring--) in your SecurityConfiguration class. This is the simplest option.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/error*");
}
```

### 2. Implement the [ErrorController](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorController.html) interface

The security filterchain will not be called for request mappings included in a controller that implements ErrorController.

See Spring's own [BasicErrorController](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/BasicErrorController.html) for reference([source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/BasicErrorController.java)).

This second option is preferable as it removes any requirement for a redirect in your filter. Instead, it lets Spring Security do the heavy lifting for routing requests through the auth process. As long as there's no authenticated [Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) in the session's SecurityContext when the security filterchain has finished processing, spring security will return a 401 and return the error page specified by your ErrorController.